# App for stable marriage problem?

Tags: applications

Today I spoke with a theater manager who needs to match 7 directors with 7 playwrights. Clearly, this is an instance of the "stable marriage problem", which can be addressed using the Gale–Shapley algorithm. My question is, what would be the easiest practical way for the theater manager to accomplish this? Is there an app into which each director and playwright can enter their preferences, which will then come back with 7 stable pairings?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Comment: I don't know from apps, but there's this online: http://mathsite.math.berkeley.edu/smp/smp.html See whether it's good enough for your purposes. Here's another one that looks promising: http://sephlietz.com/gale-shapley/

Comment: Try this:  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StableMarriages/

Comment: The Gale-Shapley algorithm makes a certain guarantee, and it is not necessarily the guarantee you want. In particular, it treats men and women extremely asymmetrically: it is optimal for the men and pessimal for the women. So choosing to use Gale-Shapley on this situation means choosing to potentially screw over either the directors or the playwrights.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! Will check these suggestions.   @Qiaochu Yuan: Is there another algorithm that would achieve stability but tend toward more fairness?

Comment: http://sephlietz.com/gale-shapley could be used -- though it assumes just one person is entering all the info. I'd love to see a client-server architecture where people can send in their preferences, and when all the info has been received, the server displays the pairings.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it will be helpful for you. You need only to insert your names.
https://github.com/TelychkoVitalii/JS_algorithms/blob/master/game_theory/stable_marriage_problem.js